# mysqlvb query for beginners

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am using Vb.net 2010 and MySQL.
Insert is working but got problem in update.

```
con.Open()

Dim cmd As New Odbc.odbcCommand("update date1 set event_title='" + txteventtitle.Text + "',description='" + rchdescription.Text + "',calender='" + DateTimePicker1.Value.Date() + "')", con)

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

con.Close()
```

This query doesn't update my record into table.
As i m beginner i need step by step procedure to update a query.
I am not using any datagrid to display my records.

Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: What is the error? Also are you sure that "',calender='" is right?Maybe is calendar?

Comment: Also you close the brackets ) but you haven't opened them

Comment: Why do you use ODBC instead of a more complete ADO.NET provider like the [MySql Connector](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/)?

Comment: Two important notes: you should switch [Option Strict On](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/08/option-strict-and-option-explicit-in-vbnet-2005.html) and you should look into [parameterised queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i) as your code is vulnerable to sql injection

Answer (score 0):

Remove the closing paren `+ "')"` in the query.